# Vue.js - Emit event from directive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

Is it possible to emit a custom event *from* the directive *in* the component to which this directive is attached.

I was expecting it to work as described in example, but it does not.

Example:

```
//Basic Directive
<script>
  Vue.directive('foo', {
    bind(el, binding, vnode) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        //vnode.context.$emit('bar'); <- this will trigger in parent
        vnode.$emit('bar');
      }, 3000);
    }
  });
</script>


//Basic Component
<template>
  <button v-foo @bar="change">{{label}}</button>
</template>
<script>
  export default{
    data() {
      return {
        label: 'i dont work'
      }
    },
    methods: {
      change() {
        this.label = 'I DO WORK!';
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Any ideas on the matter? Am I missing something?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0aum3osq/4/

**Update 1:**

Okay, i've found that if I call `vnode.data.on.bar.fn();` (or `fns()` in latest Vue versions) in directive it will trigger `bar` event handler.

**Update 2:**

Temporary solution:

```
  /*temp. solution*/
  var emit = (vnode, name, data) => {
    var handlers = vnode.data.on;

    if (handlers && handlers.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      var handler = handlers[name];
      var fn = handler.fns || handler.fn;

      if (typeof fn === 'function') {
        fn(data);
      }
    }
  } 

//Basic Directive
<script>
  Vue.directive('foo', {
    bind(el, binding, vnode) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        emit(vnode, 'bar');
      }, 3000);
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

So the solution I am using in Vue 2+ (considering there were no answers so far):

In directive add method:

```
var emit = (vnode, name, data) => {
  var handlers = (vnode.data && vnode.data.on) ||
    (vnode.componentOptions && vnode.componentOptions.listeners);

  if (handlers && handlers[name]) {
    handlers[name].fns(data);
  }
}
```

And call it this way:

```
bind(el, binding, vnode) {
  emit(vnode, 'bar' , {some: 'event', data: 'here'});
}
```

The benefits of an approach:

1 Keep the same code-style in your project, meaning that every handler can be declared as 

`v-on:handler_name` and be handled in meaningful (for developer) way. Other solutions, like sending callback as parameter, are sometimes confusing and not obvious without digging into documentation/code.

2 Using built-in events system also allows to gracefully handle event objects. For example, this code will work perfectly fine:

```
<button v-foo @bar="bar(1, $event, 2)">{{label}}</button>
...
methods: {
  bar(one, event, two) { console.log(one, event, two); }
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

In v2.1+ you can use this inside directive binding:

```
vnode.context.$emit(eventname)
```

Comment: Works great! Your emit function call is missing the ending bracket. I tried to edit, but SO says I must edit 6 characters.

Comment: `vnode.context.$emit()` is not working in this example under vue@v2.5, how to fix it ? But the emit function still works well.

Comment: In my experience you can only call `vnode.context.$emit('name')` after an event has been dispatched...

`element.addEvenetListener('click', () => { 
 vnode.context.$emit('handleClick');  });`
works! But doing a plain `vnode.context.$emit('handleClick')` 

outside of an event trigger doesn't actually call the emit properly thus you can't listen for it. I could be wrong, but this is what I just experienced in vue@2.5.

Comment: Is it just me, or is the parent emitting the event, not the actual element with the directive?

Comment: That would explain why it's not emitting it from the right element. Thanks!

Comment: Does not work with Vue 3

Answer (score 4):

Your solution was not working for me. Indeed vnode.data.on was always undefined

What worked to trigger an event was

```
 vnode.child.$emit('myevent');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: gave undefined for me; ```vnode.context.$emit``` is a function in Vue v.2.1.10 at least

Comment: vnode.child.$emit('bar'); $emit of undefined for Vue v2.4.2.  https://jsfiddle.net/Jimsan/vuv80dpn/7/

Answer (score 3):

I know it is an old issue, but if someone has problems with this and it is not working. You can use use javascript custom events events.

```
    vue.directive('click',{bind(el, binding, vnode) {
        el.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
            const event = new CustomEvent('customevent', {detail: {
                                                          custom: "data", 
                                                          can: "be", 
                                                          in: "detail property"}, bubbles: true});
            el.dispatchEvent(event);
        })
    }
})
```

now i can use it like

```
<div v-click @customevent="func">hello world</div>
```

i do not have to set `$event` because the default is standard emitted as last param. this event has a `detail` property, which contains your custom data in this case this object:

```
{custom: "data", 
 can: "be", 
 in: "detail property"}
```

*src https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7147*

Answer (score 3):

The above answers are great but some of them are out-of-date. Here's the way I solve the problem by integrating them into a workable POC.

```js
// src/directives/ClickOutside.js
export default {
  stopProp(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  },
  bind(el, binding, vnode) {
    el._clickOutside = e => {
      vnode.context.$emit(binding.expression, e);
    };
    el.addEventListener('click', binding.def.stopProp);
    document.body.addEventListener('click', el._clickOutside);
  },
  unbind() {
    if (!el._clickOutside) {
      return;
    }
    el.removeEventListener('click', binding.def.stopProp);
    document.body.removeEventListener('click', el._clickOutside);
    delete el._clickOutside;
  }
};

// src/directives/index.js
import Vue from 'vue';
import ClickOutside from './ClickOutside';

Vue.directive('ClickOutside', ClickOutside);
```

Import the directives in main.js:

```js
// src/main.js
import './directives';
```

Use the directive with listening to the event emission in a Vue component:

```js
// src/components/Component.vue
<template>
  <!-- Please fill in sensible context. This example doesn't really care about the DOM presentation -->
  <div @click="showElement" v-click-outside="hideElement">
    <div v-if="shouldShow">Hello</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      shouldShow: true
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$on('hideElement', this.hideElement);
  },
  destroyed() {
    this.$off('hideElement', this.hideElement);
  },
  methods: {
    showElement() {
      this.shouldShow = true;
    },
    hideElement() {
      this.shouldShow = false;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Basically, in `vnode.context.$emit`, the `binding.expression` is the string (i.e., "hideElement" in this example) you declared in the `v-close-outside`. To retrieve the emission from the directive, use `this.$on('hideElement')` to listen to it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is just use dispatchEvent on the `el` like this

```
el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can emit custom native javascript events. Create a directive that dispatches an event from the node, using node.dispatchEvent

```
let handleOutsideClick;
Vue.directive('out-click', {
    bind (el, binding, vnode) {

        handleOutsideClick = (e) => {
            e.stopPropagation()
            const handler = binding.value

            if (el.contains(e.target)) {
                el.dispatchEvent(new Event('out-click')) <-- HERE
            }
        }

        document.addEventListener('click', handleOutsideClick)
        document.addEventListener('touchstart', handleOutsideClick)
    },
    unbind () {
        document.removeEventListener('click', handleOutsideClick)
        document.removeEventListener('touchstart', handleOutsideClick)
    }
})
```

Which can be used like this

```
h3( v-out-click @click="$emit('show')" @out-click="$emit('hide')" )
```

Answer (score -1):

@euvl's solution is fine, but i think it's easier and cleaner to just pass a function as an argument to your directive. Seems to simplify the interface to your directive as well.

```js
<script>
  Vue.directive('foo', {
    bind(el, binding) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        binding.value();
      }, 3000);
    }
  });
</script>

<template>
  <button v-foo="change">{{label}}</button>
</template>

<script>
  export default{
    data() {
      return {
        label: 'i dont work'
      }
    },
    methods: {
      change() {
        this.label = 'I DO WORK!';
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I am afraid this does not answer the question. Also, if, for example, you have directive `v-draggable`, and you want to have events `on-drag-start`, `on-drag-end`, `on-drag`, `on-drag-error` I don't think your approach will be that clean. Good call though.

Comment: @euvl i suppose it depends a bit on the directive (OP wasn't very specific). I suppose you could give an argument to the callback as well, but then you're re-building events in a way, so your solution might be cleaner then.