# How to call the method of element and pass arguments from directive Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I need to call method of element from directive and pass some parameters to this method.

```
<div id="app">
  <div >
    <button
            @mousetrapped="trapped"
            v-keyboardtrap
          >
              keyboardtrap
    </button>
  <div/>
</div>

<script>
Vue.directive('keyboardtrap', {
  bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
    el.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown);

    function onKeyDown(e) {
      vnode.context.$emit('mousetrapped', e)
    }
  },
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    trapped (e) {
      alert('trapped' + e)
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

This example on codepen: https://codepen.io/4e4e4i/pen/OJLewNr

Comment: What are you trying to achive (functional) ? because a button already has an @click event on it?

Comment: @dreijntjens, it's just example, i need to catch keydown event and then call method from component in directive and pass some parameters there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my solution. It's needToPassDatas is you needed to pass an argument data

```
<div id="app">
  <div>
      <button @mousetrapped="trapped"  v-keyboardtrap="needToPassDatas">
          keyboardtrap
      </button>
  <div/>
</div>

Vue.directive('keyboardtrap', {
  bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {

    el.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown);

    function onKeyDown(e) {
       var handlers = (vnode.data && vnode.data.on) ||
                      (vnode.componentOptions && vnode.componentOptions.listeners);

       if (handlers && handlers['mousetrapped']) {
          handlers['mousetrapped'].fns(binding.value);
       }
    }
  },
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    trapped (e) {
      alert('trapped' + e)
    }
  }
})
```

Ref by: [vuejs.org Dynamic Directive Arguments](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Dynamic-Directive-Arguments), [stackoverflow.com Trigger emit in directive method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40655333/vue-js-emit-event-from-directive#answer-40720172)

Comment: I changed completely plz try it now

Comment: I changed completely with that trapped method alert. plz try it now @4e4e4i